# Download the metadata from peers failed by bep_0009 [golang]

Tags: go, bittorrent, dht

When I send an extension request message to peers, but no response from peers.

I got Handshake and Extended Bitfield and Have Piece ok, but no extension data message.

This is my Golang code.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/IncSW/go-bencode"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func readBuffer(conn *net.TCPConn, size uint32) ([]byte, error) {
    //temp := make([]byte, size)
    //_, err := conn.Read(temp)
    //if err != nil {
    //  return nil, fmt.Errorf("read %d bytes message failed: %v", size, err)
    //}
    //return temp, nil
    buffer := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second * 120))
    _, err := io.CopyN(buffer, conn, int64(size))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("read %d bytes message failed: %v", size, err)
    }
    return buffer.Bytes(), nil
}

func next(conn *net.TCPConn) ([]byte, error) {
    buffer, err := readBuffer(conn, 4)
    if nil != err {
        return nil, err
    }
    buffer, err = readBuffer(conn, binary.BigEndian.Uint32(buffer))
    if nil != err {
        return nil, err
    }
    return buffer, nil
}

func getHandshake(infoHash []byte, nodeId []byte) []byte {
    packet := []byte{19, 66, 105, 116, 84, 111, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 32, 112, 114, 111, 116, 111, 99, 111, 108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 1}
    packet = append(packet, infoHash...)
    packet = append(packet, nodeId...)
    return packet
}

// http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0009.html
// http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0010.html
func peerWire(addr string, infoHash []byte, nodeId []byte) {
    dial, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", addr, 10*time.Second)
    if nil != err {
        return
    }
    conn := dial.(*net.TCPConn)
    conn.SetLinger(0)
    defer conn.Close()
    // handshake
    handshake := getHandshake(infoHash, nodeId)
    conn.Write(handshake)
    handshakeRes := make([]byte, 68)
    _, err = conn.Read(handshakeRes)
    if !(bytes.Equal(handshake[:20], handshakeRes[:20]) && handshakeRes[25]&0x10 != 0) {
        log.Println("invalid handshake response")
        return
    }
    // extended handshake
    // [length prefix][BitTorrent message ID][extended message ID]
    extendedHandshake, _ := bencode.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{
        "m": map[string]interface{}{"ut_metadata": 1},
    })
    extendedHandshake = append([]byte{20, 0}, extendedHandshake...)
    size := make([]byte, 4)
    extendedHandshake = append(size, extendedHandshake...)
    conn.Write(extendedHandshake)
    buffer, err := next(conn)
    if nil != err {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    if 0 < len(buffer) {
        msgUT, err := bencode.Unmarshal(buffer[2:])
        if nil != err {
            log.Println("error")
            return
        }
        metadataSize, ok := msgUT.(map[string]interface{})["metadata_size"].(int64)
        if !ok {
            return
        }
        m, ok := msgUT.(map[string]interface{})["m"].(map[string]interface{})
        if !ok {
            return
        }
        utMetadata, ok := m["ut_metadata"].(int64)
        if !ok {
            return
        }
        numberOfPieces := metadataSize / 16384
        if metadataSize%16384 != 0 {
            numberOfPieces++
        }

        for i := 0; i < int(numberOfPieces); i++ {
            packet, err := bencode.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{"msg_type":0, "piece":int(i)})
            if nil != err {
                log.Println(err)
            }
            packet = append([]byte{20, byte(utMetadata)}, packet...)
            size := make([]byte, 4)
            binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(size, uint32(len(packet)))
            packet = append(size, packet...)
            conn.Write(packet)
            break
        }
        piece := make([]byte, 0)
        for {
            buffer, err := next(conn)
            if nil != err {
                log.Println(err.Error())
                break
            }
            log.Println(buffer)
            if 20 != buffer[0] {
                continue
            }
            log.Println("buffer: ", buffer)
            piece = append(piece, buffer...)
        }
        log.Println("index :", bytes.Index(piece, []byte("ee")))
    }
}

func main() {
    nodeId := make([]byte, 20)
    rand.Read(nodeId)
    infoHash := []byte{231, 130, 244, 163, 244, 122, 203, 232, 78, 218, 29, 116, 240, 232, 146, 236, 199, 72, 132, 254}
    addr := "203.81.67.114:55254"
    peerWire(addr, infoHash, nodeId)
}
```

I think the extension request message "[]byte{0, 0, 0, 27, 20, 2, 100, 53, 58, 112, 105, 101, 99, 101, 105, 48, 101, 56, 58, 109, 115, 103, 95, 116, 121, 112, 101, 105, 48, 101, 101}" format is correct.

[image]

[WireShark Dump Data](https://share-bucket-one.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/bep_0009.pcapng)

Answer (score 1):

From the pcap:

```
00000044  00 00 00 00 14 00 64 31  3a 6d 64 31 31 3a 75 74   ......d1 :md11:ut
00000054  5f 6d 65 74 61 64 61 74  61 69 31 65 65 65         _metadat ai1eee
```

You're sending `00 00 00 00` as the length for the extension handshake. That will be interpreted as a keepalive message and the rest as a message with length `14 00 64 31` and type `3a` i.e. complete nonsense.

---

Complete pcap:
`00000000  13 42 69 74 54 6f 72 72  65 6e 74 20 70 72 6f 74   .BitTorr ent prot
00000010  6f 63 6f 6c 00 00 00 00  00 10 00 01 e7 82 f4 a3   ocol.... ........
00000020  f4 7a cb e8 4e da 1d 74  f0 e8 92 ec c7 48 84 fe   .z..N..t .....H..
00000030  0d 3a 6c 0f 88 e8 41 45  b9 96 b4 52 62 eb 33 cc   .:l...AE ...Rb.3.
00000040  ca 73 8b bf                                        .s..
    00000000  13 42 69 74 54 6f 72 72  65 6e 74 20 70 72 6f 74   .BitTorr ent prot
    00000010  6f 63 6f 6c 00 00 00 00  00 10 00 05 e7 82 f4 a3   ocol.... ........
    00000020  f4 7a cb e8 4e da 1d 74  f0 e8 92 ec c7 48 84 fe   .z..N..t .....H..
    00000030  2d 55 54 33 35 34 53 2d  58 ae 73 ad 79 d9 8e d6   -UT354S- X.s.y...
    00000040  bd be b0 5f 00 00 00 e6  14 00 64 31 3a 65 69 30   ..._.... ..d1:ei0
    00000050  65 34 3a 69 70 76 34 34  3a cb 51 43 72 31 32 3a   e4:ipv44 :.QCr12:
    00000060  63 6f 6d 70 6c 65 74 65  5f 61 67 6f 69            complete _agoi
00000044  00 00 00 00 14 00 64 31  3a 6d 64 31 31 3a 75 74   ......d1 :md11:ut
00000054  5f 6d 65 74 61 64 61 74  61 69 31 65 65 65         _metadat ai1eee
    0000006D  33 65 31 3a 6d 64 31 31  3a 75 70 6c 6f 61 64 5f   3e1:md11 :upload_
    0000007D  6f 6e 6c 79 69 33 65 31  31 3a 6c 74 5f 64 6f 6e   onlyi3e1 1:lt_don
    0000008D  74 68 61 76 65 69 37 65  31 32 3a 75 74 5f 68 6f   thavei7e 12:ut_ho
    0000009D  6c 65 70 75 6e 63 68 69  34 65 31 31 3a 75 74 5f   lepunchi 4e11:ut_
    000000AD  6d 65 74 61 64 61 74 61  69 32 65 36 3a 75 74 5f   metadata i2e6:ut_
    000000BD  70 65 78 69 31 65 31 30  3a 75 74 5f 63 6f 6d 6d   pexi1e10 :ut_comm
    000000CD  65 6e 74 69 36 65 65 31  33 3a 6d 65 74 61 64 61   enti6ee1 3:metada
    000000DD  74 61 5f 73 69 7a 65 69  38 38 38 32 65 31 3a 70   ta_sizei 8882e1:p
    000000ED  69 35 35 32 35 34 65 34  3a 72 65 71 71 69 32 35   i55254e4 :reqqi25
    000000FD  35 65 31 3a 76 31 35 3a  ce bc 54 6f 72 72 65 6e   5e1:v15: ..Torren
    0000010D  74 20 33 2e 35 2e 34 32  3a 79 70 69 33 31 34 30   t 3.5.42 :ypi3140
    0000011D  38 65 36 3a 79 6f 75 72  69 70 34 3a 75 8b d0 19   8e6:your ip4:u...
    0000012D  65 00 00 00 38 05 ff ef  ff df f7 f7 ff ff ff ff   e...8... ........
    0000013D  ff df ff ff df ff ff ff  ef ff ff ee fe ff ff ff   ........ ........
    0000014D  6f ff ff 99 ff ff fd ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ef ff   o....... ........
    0000015D  ff fe f7 ff ff fc ff bf  ff ff bf ff c0 00 00 00   ........ ........
    0000016D  05 04 00 00 00 5a 00 00  00 05 04 00 00 00 0b 00   .....Z.. ........
    0000017D  00 00 05 04 00 00 00 e9  00 00 00 05 04 00 00 00   ........ ........
    0000018D  ea 00 00 00 05 04 00 00  01 64 00 00 00 05 04 00   ........ .d......
    0000019D  00 01 5f 00 00 00 05 04  00 00 00 d3 00 00 00 05   .._..... ........
    000001AD  04 00 00 01 7f 00 00 00  05 04 00 00 00 1a 00 00   ........ ........
    000001BD  00 05 04 00 00 00 24 00  00 00 05 04 00 00 01 89   ......$. ........
    000001CD  00 00 00 05 04 00 00 00  ee 00 00 00 05 04 00 00   ........ ........
    000001DD  01 06 00 00 00 05 04 00  00 00 ed 00 00 00 05 04   ........ ........
    000001ED  00 00 00 2c 00 00 00 05  04 00 00 00 93 00 00 00   ...,.... ........
    000001FD  05 04 00 00 00 ab 00 00  00 05 04 00 00 00 d0 00   ........ ........
    0000020D  00 00 05 04 00 00 00 b7  00 00 00 05 04 00 00 01   ........ ........
    0000021D  a1 00 00 00 05 04 00 00  00 72 00 00 00 05 04 00   ........ .r......
    0000022D  00 01 43 00 00 00 05 04  00 00 01 7e 00 00 00 05   ..C..... ...~....
    0000023D  04 00 00 00 af                                     .....
00000062  00 00 00 1b 14 02 64 38  3a 6d 73 67 5f 74 79 70   ......d8 :msg_typ
00000072  65 69 30 65 35 3a 70 69  65 63 65 69 30 65 65      ei0e5:pi ecei0ee
    00000242  13 42 69 74 54 6f 72 72  65 6e 74 20 70 72 6f 74   .BitTorr ent prot
    00000252  6f 63 6f 6c 00 00 00 00  00 10 00 05 e7 82 f4 a3   ocol.... ........
    00000262  f4 7a cb e8 4e da 1d 74  f0 e8 92 ec c7 48 84 fe   .z..N..t .....H..
    00000272  2d 55 54 33 35 34 53 2d  58 ae 73 ad 79 d9 8e d6   -UT354S- X.s.y...
    00000282  bd be b0 5f 00 00 00 e6  14 00 64 31 3a 65 69 30   ..._.... ..d1:ei0
    00000292  65 34 3a 69 70 76 34 34  3a cb 51 43 72 31 32 3a   e4:ipv44 :.QCr12:
    000002A2  63 6f 6d 70 6c 65 74 65  5f 61 67 6f 69 33 65 31   complete _agoi3e1
    000002B2  3a 6d 64 31 31 3a 75 70  6c 6f 61 64 5f 6f 6e 6c   :md11:up load_onl
    000002C2  79 69 33 65 31 31 3a 6c  74 5f 64 6f 6e 74 68 61   yi3e11:l t_dontha
    000002D2  76 65 69 37 65 31 32 3a  75 74 5f 68 6f 6c 65 70   vei7e12: ut_holep
    000002E2  75 6e 63 68 69 34 65 31  31 3a 75 74 5f 6d 65 74   unchi4e1 1:ut_met
    000002F2  61 64 61 74 61 69 32 65  36 3a 75 74 5f 70 65 78   adatai2e 6:ut_pex
    00000302  69 31 65 31 30 3a 75 74  5f 63 6f 6d 6d 65 6e 74   i1e10:ut _comment
    00000312  69 36 65 65 31 33 3a 6d  65 74 61 64 61 74 61 5f   i6ee13:m etadata_
    00000322  73 69 7a 65 69 38 38 38  32 65 31 3a 70 69 35 35   sizei888 2e1:pi55
    00000332  32 35 34 65 34 3a 72 65  71 71 69 32 35 35 65 31   254e4:re qqi255e1
    00000342  3a 76 31 35 3a ce bc 54  6f 72 72 65 6e 74 20 33   :v15:..T orrent 3
    00000352  2e 35 2e 34 32 3a 79 70  69 33 31 34 30 38 65 36   .5.42:yp i31408e6
    00000362  3a 79 6f 75 72 69 70 34  3a 75 8b d0 19 65 00 00   :yourip4 :u...e..
    00000372  00 38 05 ff ef ff df f7  f7 ff ff ff ff ff df ff   .8...... ........
    00000382  ff df ff ff ff ef ff ff  ee fe ff ff ff 6f ff ff   ........ .....o..
    00000392  99 ff ff fd ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ef ff ff fe f7   ........ ........
    000003A2  ff ff fc ff bf ff ff bf  ff c0 00 00 00 05 04 00   ........ ........
    000003B2  00 00 5a 00 00 00 05 04  00 00 00 0b 00 00 00 05   ..Z..... ........
    000003C2  04 00 00 00 e9 00 00 00  05 04 00 00 00 ea 00 00   ........ ........
    000003D2  00 05 04 00 00 01 64 00  00 00 05 04 00 00 01 5f   ......d. ......._
    000003E2  00 00 00 05 04 00 00 00  d3 00 00 00 05 04 00 00   ........ ........
    000003F2  01 7f 00 00 00 05 04 00  00 00 1a 00 00 00 05 04   ........ ........
    00000402  00 00 00 24 00 00 00 05  04 00 00 01 89 00 00 00   ...$.... ........
    00000412  05 04 00 00 00 ee 00 00  00 05 04 00 00 01 06 00   ........ ........
    00000422  00 00 05 04 00 00 00 ed  00 00 00 05 04 00 00 00   ........ ........
    00000432  2c 00 00 00 05 04 00 00  00 93 00 00 00 05 04 00   ,....... ........
    00000442  00 00 ab 00 00 00 05 04  00 00 00 d0 00 00 00 05   ........ ........
    00000452  04 00 00 00 b7 00 00 00  05 04 00 00 01 a1 00 00   ........ ........
    00000462  00 05 04 00 00 00 72 00  00 00 05 04 00 00 01 43   ......r. .......C
    00000472  00 00 00 05 04 00 00 01  7e 00 00 00 05 04 00 00   ........ ~.......
    00000482  00 af 00 00 00 03 09 d7  d6                        ........ .`